# Inheritence of C++11 class

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Surgery
{
public:
    Surgery();
    int getPrice();
    string getType();
protected:
    int price;
    string type;
};

Surgery::Surgery()
{
    price = 0;
    type = "";
}

int Surgery::getPrice()
{
    return price;
}

string Surgery::getType()
{
    return type;
}

class Neurosurgery :public Surgery
{
private:
    string type = "Neurosurgery";
    int price = 23000;
};
class Plastic :public Surgery
{
private:
    string type = "Plastic";
    int price = 15000;
};
class Trauma :public Surgery
{
private:
    string type = "Trauma";
    int price = 5000;
};
class Endocrine :public Surgery
{
private:
    string type = "Endocrine";
    int price = 20000;
};
class Ophthalmological :public Surgery
{
public:
    Ophthalmological();
private:
    string type;
    int price;
};

Ophthalmological::Ophthalmological():Surgery()
{
    type = "Ophthalmological";
    price = 10000;
}

int main()
{
    Ophthalmological var1;
    cout << var1.getPrice() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When i run this code i expected to see 10000
Instead i see 0

I made it really simple to avoid any mistake with const, singlone default constructors.

First Surgery constructor gets executed after Neurosurgery.

Neurosurgery constructor should overwrite values that default Surgery constructor made.

Am i using c++11 in wrong style

Comment: Delete all the data members from your derived classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are declaring tow times the variable price and type and, and when you are invoking `cout << var1.getPrice() << endl;` it takes the variable of `Surgery`. You should do:

```
class Surgery
{
public:
    Surgery();
    int getPrice();
    string getType();
protected:
    int price;
    string type;
};

class Ophthalmological :public Surgery
{
public:
    Ophthalmological();
private:
    //string type; //It has been declared into Survey
    //int price;   //It has been declared into Survey
};
```

I ran your code with this modification and return the value of the unique `price` variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the fact that it is not virtual, and there are multiple variables with the same name. So you get value from the base class Surgery. The other classes also define the variables with the same name. I think the simplest solution is this: Keep the protected variables in the base class and remove those variables from the subclasses.